# Google App Engine: how to have static & dyamic files with same parent dir? e.g. dir/css & dir/python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, directory, yaml

So for a project, I am required to group code into 3 parent folders - SourceA, SourceB and SourceC, depending on whether the code is my own, partly my own, or someone else's accordingly. These 3 folders also then have a python, javascript and misc (containing HTML & anything else) in them. For example, the structure can be seen graphically as follows:

--SourceA

----python

----javascript

----misc

--SourceB

----python

----javascript

----misc

--SourceC

----python

----javascript

----misc

Likewise, my app.yaml file can be seen below. Running locally, this works perfectly, displaying both the static and dynamic files accordingly, however, when deployed on Google App Engine, only there is a TemplateNotFound error thrown, possibly because app engine is treating the parent directory (e.g. SourceA) as a static path:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /SourceA/misc
  static_dir: SourceA/misc
- url: /SourceB/misc
  static_dir: SourceB/misc
- url: /SourceC/misc
  static_dir: SourceC/misc
- url: /SourceA/javascript
  static_dir: SourceA/javascript
- url: /SourceB/javascript
  static_dir: SourceB/javascript
- url: /SourceC/javascript
  static_dir: SourceC/javascript
- url: /.*
  script: SourceA.python.main.app
```

If I run this, I get a TemplateNotFound error thrown by both the render_template() function in Flask (which uses Jinja behind the scenes) and when I try instead with the .render() function in Jinja. If instead I remove all the static handlers just to test the principle, the python code that works as expected again...but of course the static files aren't served...i.e. by changing my app.yaml to

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: SourceA.python.main.app
```

**While I can get around this and have a fully-working site on appspot by simply making a static directory outside of the SourceA/B/C directories, this isn't ideal, as it doesn't abide by the spec I'm supposed to be following**

Anyway, hopefully I have explained the issue and if anyone knows if this is possible, then I'd be grateful for any help!

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic, but weirdly it seems that static files will be loaded without specifying a static handler in app.yaml on when deployed on app engine...but they won't be loaded if the static hanlders aren't specific when run locally...

Comment: I don't think a `template not found` error has anything to do with your url mapping.  Where is your `templates` dir?

Answer (score 0):

If your app functions properly on the development server it means that the problem is simply the file presence in a directory declared static, which by default is not app-accessible. Adding the `application_readable` flag to the handler configuration for the static dirs would address the problem, see the respective row in the [handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table.

But in general it is not a great idea to mix app code with static items.